# Position of a point changes by zoom in QGIS ? (OpenLayers plug-in doesn't show same position on different zoom levels ?)

Tags: qgis, google-maps, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I have a point layer in QGIS. I was just inspecting the points and I've realized points position changes too much as I zoom in or zoom out. Does anyone know why this is happening?

[image: zoom level 1]

[image: zoom level 2]

[image]

I'm sure Google layers plug-in is working well because many people using it everyday. Also I've checked my point layer is referenced to true coordinate system.

My question is quite straight forward and maybe stupid I don't know but I couldn't figure out why so I decided to ask it here.

Comment: Have you built pyramids for the aerial?

Comment: Nope, I've only downloaded OpenLayers plug-in and added GoogleMaps layer.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues with using the OpenLayers plugin many years ago.  You should try to use the Quick Map Services plugin and see if you have the same issue.